# Using ParametricNDSolve solution in FindRoot with a complex valued unknown

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, nonlinear

I want to find the parameter N by solving the FindRoot,

```
For[k = 5, k <= 7, k = k + 0.1,
  sol = 
    ParametricNDSolve[
      {Y''[x] + k^2 (1 - 0.1  Conjugate[Y[x]] Y[x]) Y[x] == 0, 
       Y[1] == N E^(I k), Y'[1] == I k N E^(I k)}, 
      Y[x], {x, 0, 1}, {N}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
  Ns = FindRoot[(Y'[N][0] + I k Y[N][0] == 2 I k) /. sol, {N, 0}];
  Print[Ns]]
```

`Y[x]` and `N` are a complex-valued function and number, respectively.

Comment: `N` is reserved for a Wolfram Language built-in function; do not use it for a variable name. Better yet, do **not** start any identifier names with an uppercase letter.

Comment: What is the question here? What do you expect us to do for you?

Comment: Thank you, I changed the parameters names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to find the value of [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N) such that `Y` satisfies your ODE and also `Y'[0] + I k Y[0] == 2 I k`.

If so, the following should code should do so. Note that I replaced [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N) with `n` since it is not a good idea to use [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N) as a variable (it is a protected function in Mathematica):

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    Y''[x]+k^2 (1-0.1 Conjugate[Y[x]] Y[x]) Y[x]==0,
    Y[1] == n E^(I k),
    Y'[1] == I k n E^(I k)
    },
    {Y[0], Y'[0]},
    {x, 0, 1},
    {k, n}
];

ns[k_] := n /. FindRoot[sol[k, n] . {k I, 1} == 2 k I, {n, .5+.5I}]

Table[ns[k], {k, 5, 7, .1}]
```

> {0.962051 - 0.267214 I, 0.960445 - 0.272843 I, 0.958826 - 0.278492 I, 
>    0.957198 - 0.284145 I, 0.955563 - 0.289789 I, 0.953924 - 0.29541 I, 
>    0.952283 - 0.300994 I, 0.95064 - 0.306528 I, 0.948996 - 0.312 I, 
>    0.947349 - 0.317401 I, 0.9457 - 0.322723 I, 0.944045 - 0.327961 I, 
>    0.942383 - 0.333111 I, 0.94071 - 0.338174 I, 0.939023 - 0.343151 I, 
>    0.937318 - 0.348046 I, 0.93559 - 0.352868 I, 0.933836 - 0.357624 I, 
>    0.932049 - 0.362324 I, 0.930225 - 0.36698 I, 0.928361 - 0.371606 I}

By the way, I expect that there is a way to encode the LHS boundary constraint `Y'[0] + I k Y[0] == 2 I k` into your ode, but I haven't pursued that idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works well.